# What is wrong in my solution? 2nd order ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ODE, however I can't find the solution as it's given in the book.
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
y''(x)=f(x), \qquad 0<x< 1 \\
y(0)=y(1)=0
\end{cases}
\end{align}

**My solution:**
\begin{align}
y'(x)&= \int f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x=F(x)+C_1 \\
y(x)&= \int (F(x)+C_1)\, \mathrm{d}x=\int F(x) \, \mathrm{d}x+C_1x + C_2
\end{align}

> The solution:
>   \begin{align}
> y'(x)&=\int_0^x f(y) \, \mathrm{d} y +C_1 \\
> y(x)&=\int_0^x \int_0^z f(y) \,  \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}z+ C_1x+C_2
> \end{align}

**Questions:**

Why definite integrals in the solution?

Where are the limits from?

Why is there a double integral in the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: The integrals don't match because the integrands are not the same.

Comment: I see nothing wrong in your solution. For uniformity, you might have written $y(x)=\mathbb F(x)+C_1x+C_2$, where $\mathbb F$ is an antiderivative of $F$.

Comment: In the official solution, it is a little contradictory (but not wrong) to combine a definite integral with an integration constant.

Comment: There's a double integral in your solution as well.

Comment: From far away, I prefer your solution to the official one ! $\to +1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Can you clarify the contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

You have no initial condition for $y'$ (I mean $y'(0)$ isn't given) so all you can do for the first integration is an undefinite integral,

$$y'(x)=\int f(t)\,dt+C=F(t)+C.$$

Now for the second integration, you can use the fact that $y(0)=0$ and use a definite integral

$$y(x)=0+\int_0^xy'(u)\,du=\int_0^x(F(u)+C)\,du=\int_0^xF(u)\,du+Cx.$$

then plugging the final condition,

$$\int_0^1F(u)\,du+C=0$$ and

$$y(x)=\int_0^xF(u)\,du-\left(\int_0^1F(u)\,du\right)x.$$

---

If you don't want to use the intermediate $F$, then a double definite integral can do, such as

$$y(x)=\int_{u=0}^x\int_{t=u_0}^u f(t)\,dt\,du-\left(\int_{u=0}^1\int_{t=u_0}^u f(t)\,dt\,du\right)x,$$

where $u_0$ is arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question regarding the limits. Why to you integrate from $0$ to $x$ instead of $0$ to $1$ (as given in the problem).

Comment: @JDoeDoe: which integral are you talking about ?

Comment: Your second integration, "Now for the second integration, you can use....".

Comment: @JDoeDoe Hem, for this integral I use both $0,x$ and $0,1$ limits.

Comment: Hmm, I try to clarify. You use definite integrals, can I use indefinite integrals? I mean, I tried $y'(x)=F(x)+C_1$ and $y(x)=\int (F(x)+C_1) \, dx= \int F(t)\, dt+C_1x+C_2$. Now find constants. $x=0$ and $y=0$ gives $0 = \int F(t) \, dt +0+C_2$ so $C_2=-\int F(t) \, dt.$ So $y(x)=\int F(t) \, dt +C_1x- \int F(t) \, dt=C_1x$ Which is wrong...